# Impact of generator start-up on its health

Tags: motors, stresses, generator, diesel, maintenance

In [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43749514), the authors state that the wear effect of a genset star-up is comparable to the wear cause by 1 to 4 minutes running at full load.

This paper dates from 1993, I am looking for a more recent reference, or directly for answer.

Do startups contribute to the wear and tear, and how much?

Comment: Why do you need a more recent reference? Do you think that newer engines don't suffer more wear during start-up? Cold oil, lack of lubrication at initial rotating conditions... Many engine builders will "spin" freshly built engines to get 60psi of oil pressure and lubricate the engine thoroughly just on the starter with spark plugs removed before firing it up. Why do you think they would go to that effort?

Answer (score 2):

Startup wear in internal combustion engines happens mostly because the engine is turning before the oil pump has had a chance to develop full pressure and move oil to all the moving parts of the engine. Some engines have *pre-oiler* pumps installed in them which are turned on before engine start to ensure proper lubrication. Others rely on the user to pre-oil the engine by manually turning the engine over enough times to get the oil pump primed and operating first, before starting.

Note also that there are applications (shaft bearings in large power plant generators and turbines) where even when the machinery is not operating, full oil pressure is maintained by auxiliary pumps to guarantee that the idle time does not give the huge masses involved the opportunity to squeeze all the oil out of the bearings, leading to their destruction when the system is restarted.

Comment: There are oiling systems in paper mills that deliver oil in tonnes per second all over the floor when someone pushes the wrong button :) was paid to help clear up...

Comment: @solar mike, YOWZA!!!

Comment: When there's a river of hydraulic oil pouring down the staircase, it's never a good thing.